# Loki apt update gives a lot of errors

Tags: release-loki, updates, ppa

Basically after installing Loki (using the homefolder from my prior ubuntu installation) and upon installing i opened up the terminal and did

```
sudo apt update
```

Which gave me a surprising amount of errors. Now, I have just shrugged at it for a while now, but I feel i had to do something about it sooner or later, and it really irks me. so here's my output of 
, `sudo apt update` can anyone tell me what exactly is the problem here?

```
    Ign:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki InRelease
Ign:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki-updates InRelease     
Hit:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Ign:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki InRelease
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease         
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:9 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease   
Hit:10 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki InRelease
Err:13 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:2010:0:1::1 80]
Hit:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                  
Err:15 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki-updates Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:2010:0:1::1 80]
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release
  404  Not Found
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:19 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease   
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [54.6 kB]
Hit:22 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [45.7 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [32.2 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [37.0 kB]
Hit:26 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
E: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:29 and /etc/apt/sources.list:81
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:31 and /etc/apt/sources.list:83
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:91
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:49 and /etc/apt/sources.list:101
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list:103
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list:105
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes without commenting the reason. Or at least flagging the question for problems.

Comment: To you who downvoted, please comment on WHY you dislike the question so that i may add the necessary information.

I'm sure no one on stack exchange downvotes stuff because the just don't think the product could fail that way.

It really has been failing badly this way ever since i installed it. and i really am not sure why, as it did so before i got the chance to add any new ppa's myself, and those I've added are not failing.

Comment: I know you don't think the extra PPAs are to blame, but for the sake of completeness, could you do as suggested below and post the output of `apt update` with just the default repos enabled? It makes it easier for people to help who aren't familiar with your system setup :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have conflicting PPAs on your setup. Remove all the unnecessary ones and try again.

If you really need the PPAs, add them one by one and `apt update` again then weed out those that cause conflicts.